# Android Studio: Writing Radio Button ID to File

Tags: android, file, radio-button, storage

i write a kind of poll for Android.
I got 3 Radio Buttons in a Radio Group and a Button to get to the next question.
Now I want, that the Name or the ID of the picked button will be written into a file on the internal storage by pressing the "Next"-Button.

I think, that I have to write the ID of the picked Button into a String and write this String than in a file. But I have no idea how to do this.

Thanks

Comment: You should at least try to do some research and write a bit of code. If that code does not work, we are happy to help, but SO is no replacement for reading the docs.

Answer (score 0):

why are you writing the id of the button. Id can be changed by android later so instead you should save name/tag or position of that radio button. And why do you want to save this to file? You can use [SharedPreferences](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm) to save the data to fetch it next time when you open the app.